# Adjugate for the derivative operation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $P_3$ be the set of all polynomials at most degree $3$ and let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ be the inner product such that $\langle p, q \rangle = a_nb_n + \dots+a_0b_0$ when $p(x) = a_nx^n+ \dots +a_0$ and $q(x)=b_nx^n + \dots +b_0$. Determine the adjugate $D^\star : P_2 \to P_3$ of $D: P_3 \to P_2$.

The adjuage matrix is $\operatorname{adj}(A)=C^T$. If $D$ can be expressed as $$D = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 3\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

then the cofactor would be $$\begin{pmatrix}  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -6 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

and the transpose $$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&-6\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

so $D^{\star}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&-6\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$? I feel like this is not correct...

Comment: You are using 4x4 matrices, but $P_2$ is only 3-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess that you were asked to find not the adjugate but the *adjoint* operator. In this case
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle D p(x), q(x) \rangle 
&= 
\left\langle \sum_n n a_n x^{n-1},\sum_n b_n x^n \right\rangle 
\\&=
\left\langle \sum_n (n+1) a_{n+1} x^n,\sum_n b_n x^n \right\rangle 
\\&=
\sum_n (n+1) a_{n+1} \cdot b_n 
\\&= \sum_n a_n \cdot n b_{n-1} 
\\&=
\left\langle \sum_n a_n x^n,\sum_n n b_{n-1} x^n \right\rangle 
\\&=
\left\langle \sum_n a_n x^n,\sum_n (n+1) b_n x^{n+1} \right\rangle 
\\&= \langle p(x), D^\star q(x) \rangle
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore
$$
D^\star q(x) = x D(x \cdot q(x)).
$$
In particular
$$
D^\star (b_0+ b_1 x + b_2 x^2) = 0+b_0 x+ 2b_1 x^2 +  3 b_2 x^3.
$$

If you prefer matrix notation then $D:P_3\to P_2$ is simply
$$
D=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 &0 & 2& 0 \\
0 &0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the (Hermitian) adjoint operator corresponds to the transposed matrix:
$$
D^\star = D ^{\rm T}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0 & 0  \\
1 &0 & 0 \\
0 &2 & 0 \\
0 &0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$